# [Discord.Js]How to get a new save (array) when on another server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I go to the first server, I use the command to save the array
The second server uses the command to save the array, But save the same

I want It Use Another New Array ,How Can i Do?

```
const Music_Queue = new Array();
class Music {
    
    constructor() {
        this.connection = {};
    }

    play(msg) {
        //if Bot Not Join The Server
        if (!this.connection[msg.guild.id]) 
        {
            music.join(msg);
        }

        //RePlace "!Play",Get Url
        const musicURL = msg.content.replace(`${prefix}play`, '');
        const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;
        if(Music_Queue.length == 0)
            {
                Music_Queue[0] = musicURL;
                music.playmusic(Music_Queue[0],voiceChannel,msg);
            }
        else
            {
                Music_Queue[Music_Queue.length + 1] = musicURL;
                getInfo(musicURL).then(info => {
                    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#0FFFFF')
                    .addField(`Add Music!『 ${info.items[0].title} 』`)
                    .setTimestamp();
                    msg.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
                })
            }
    }
```

By The Way , My Array Command Not Complete!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the **same client** and the **same variable** to store the Music array for all of your **different servers**. One way is to make different variables for each server if you know how many your bot will be on beforehand,

```
const musicQ1 = new Array(); // for server 1
const musicQ2 = new Array(); // for server 2
```

or you can make a JS object with server id's as keys and their unique arrays as values,

```
const queueObject = {"server_1_ID" : musicQ1 , "server_2_ID" : musicQ2};
```

and check to make sure a new server is allocated a space in the object in some function,

```
if (typeof queueObjects["server_new_ID"] === "undefined") {
    queueObject["server_new_ID"] = new Array();
}
```

Another option is using a database to store queue data with different locations for different server's queues. It's ultimately up to you how you want to separate and access the queue data by server.